# Getting a list/array of users using Mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do is display a list of user display names on one of my webpages by doing a simple http get request.

In my users.server.controller.js file I have this function:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { 
    User.find().populate('displayName').exec(function(err, users) {
        console.log(users);
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(users);
        }
    });
};
```

When I call this function with an `$http.get()` request from AngularJS controller I **get a 400 error.**

Here is my Mongoose User schema

```
/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    organization: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in an organization name'
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in the title of your position'
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['user']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you confuse between populate and select. populate is to be used when you have a reference to an external schema like `owner : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }`. If you want to display owner fields, then you need to call `populate('owner')` to load the user. What you need is to call `.select("displayName")` in order to retrieve only the displayName in your result.

Comment: could you mark my answer as the good one ? (need to upgrade my score...)